# Is a Co signer on a leased vehicle responsible for damages?

Tags: car, co-sign, lease

I co-signed for my sister car a couple years back. It was a leased car. And with leased cars you have to pay for all the damages you have caused. As a co signer am I the one responsible to pay for those damages that she caused?

Comment: In light of your learnings, consider whether you'd co-sign again in the future.   Sister now has a credit record, and its her's to maintain or damage as she sees fit.   It's not your problem.  You went above-and-beyond to help her, but she has to care for her financial wellness while you protect your own.

Comment: @Criggie but with a leased car you have to pay for the damages when you return it. If she doesn’t pay then I have too and I did but I need her to pay me back for it. It was over 3000 I have 3 kids. That’s why I asked if I could do something to get my money back

Comment: Would any of the damage be covered by insurance? $3000 is a lot for beyond normal wear and tear, or caused by passengers.

Comment: @TTT Can you retroactively file an insurance claim? OP has paid the $3,000 and the car is presumably no longer in OP's sister's possession.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I highly doubt you can file a car insurance claim if you no longer own the car. I was asking more as a hypothetical because I'm curious, since I can't imagine what a car must look like to have $3K in damage that is not covered by insurance...

Comment: @TTT I see. See my answer where I mention almost being on the hook for new tires. Regular maintenance is not covered by insurance. If the sister hit a large curb causing suspension damage then I can easily see that amounting to $3,000 in damages. Insurance would only come into play if you have an accident due to the suspension damage. Allstate happily tells you to [maintain your car](https://www.allstate.com/resources/car-insurance/does-car-insurance-cover-repairs).

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I agree with regular maintenance. But if you hit a curb and damage the suspension that's normally covered by collision insurance, and AFAIK collision is required with leased vehicles. If you're referring to not maintaining your tires, and because of that lack of maintenance you slide into a curb and damage the suspension, I could see the insurance company trying to possibly dispute the claim, but I doubt that's what happened here... :)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus side note- TIL (from that link) that hitting a deer is considered comprehensive instead of collision. Thanks!

Comment: @TTT I strongly advise against submitting an at-fault claim if you merely hit a curb. Getting sideswiped into one is a different story.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus how is it different than hitting a tree? Either you want to pay to fix your car out of pocket or you don't, right?

Comment: @TTT Cosmetic damage is always more expensive than something I would consider to be maintenance damage so yes, file it if you hit a tree. Tangentially, the lifetime cost of having such a silly at-fault claim of hitting a curb can be more expensive than getting it fixed yourself before turning in the car. Insurance is not your friend, it's a formality in the event that a catastrophe occurs. I had a co-worker whose wife was involved in 2 accidents where the other person was at fault. A few years later he had a no-fault and their insurance dropped their coverage.

Comment: TTT
@MonkeyZeus My point is that whether to file a claim should be a financial decision based on the value of the car, and the repair cost minus your deductible weighed against the cost of having a claim on your record. How the accident happened isn't really relevant to that decision when you're at fault.

Comment: Do you mean damage to your sister's car, or do you mean damage to another car if your sister hits it?

Comment: You should have asked this question before you co-sign anything!

Answer (score 37):

Yes.

When you co-signed, you accepted joint liability for the car (presumably because the lender didn't think your sister was sufficiently trustworthy on her own).  If there are damages, the lender can come after either or both of you to pay for them.  Since you were the financially responsible one, they're much more likely to come after you because it's a lot more likely that you have the money and a good credit score that you'd like to protect.

If your sister has the ability to pay the damages but isn't willing to pay them, you could potentially pay them and sue her in small claims court for reimbursement.  But most of the time, if a lender won't lease someone a car, there is a reason for that.  And that reason often makes the person judgement proof-- you can't get blood from a stone.

Comment: I have paid for the damages and they were well over 3000. I don’t know how a person can be hard on a car. I have kept every receipt for the damages that were fixed. And she had zero credit because she never had a credit card or a bill‍♀️

Comment: And now you know why cosigning is bad. Your sister's risks are so high that official lending institutions did not want to extend her credit. That's literally what cosigning means.

Comment: @Nelson "bad" is a matter of perspective. Many people do big favors for family and friends that a stranger would not consider.

Comment: Ok I get it. I already told myself I will never co sign for another person again. I just wanted to know if she is responsible for paying for the damages thst she caused. And if she doesn’t pay back for the damages what I could do. You don’t need to downgrade someone when they were trying to help a family member out. It’s rather rude.

Comment: @Aw4931 short answer: yes she's responsible for those damages and it's money she owes you. As to what you can do to get reimbursed, you can ask in LegalSE. I suspect small claims court. One thing to consider: how much *can* she pay? As Justin Cave said you can't get blood from a stone. Another consideration is whether you want to sour your relationship with your sister over 3K.

Comment: @Aw4931 It can be surprisingly easy to rack up thousands in damages if the dealer is both determining what counts as damage and is in charge of repairing it.  For example, replacing a panel for cosmetic damage at OEM retail prices for parts and dealer hourly rates could be over $2k.

Comment: @AlexandreAubrey  >Another consideration is whether you want to sour your relationship with your sister over 3K

I would say that it isn't his choice to make but hers.

Comment: Barmar: Co-signing is bad. If I want to help a relative or friend, and I can afford it, I'll give them the money. (This is rare obviously). I never, ever, in a million years, will co-sign for anything. People think co-signing is just a formality, in reality it is just the same as giving the person the money.

Comment: @gnasher729 I agree. I find the term "co-sign" is more predatory and taking advantage of people than anything. The reality is, it would've been better to simply sign directly with the co-signer and the agent tells the original person straight up that their credit is too poor to get the loan, instead of getting a co-signer that bears 100% of the risk. Rarely do co-signers realize they actually bear 100% of the risk, which is the real issue I have with them.

Answer (score 11):

The co-signer is responsible for the payment, and paying it was the correct course of action on your part. As for getting your money back from your sister, that may be difficult, but I believe it's possible.

You did your sister a huge favor by helping her purchase a car. You did her an even bigger favor by giving her a loan for $3000 when she needed it in an emergency. One would hope that she would be thankful for this. If she doesn't have much money right now, involving the courts is not going to help you, and would make it less likely that she would *want* to pay you back even if she could.

If you still have any sort of relationship with her, my suggestions would be:

1. Ask her to pay what she can, with some sort of minimum amount, perhaps $10-20 per week until she gets back on her feet.
2. Can she help you with something to work off a portion of the debt? Perhaps running errands for you, cleaning, babysitting, etc.

I have experience with being on both sides of these options, and the best advice I can give is to be civil and stay on good terms, if possible.

Answer (score 3):

> Is a Co signer on a leased vehicle responsible for damages?

In general, yes.

Per https://pocketsense.com/what-are-my-responsibilities-as-a-cosigner-on-a-car-lease-12445429.html

> You have the same obligation to maintain the car as the primary borrower. If the principal borrower fails to maintain and repair the car, you will have to pay, as it is a shared responsibility. If the car is not maintained, the leasing company will impose charges at the end of the lease. This can include excess wear and tear, such as damage to the interior and scratches and dings that aren't repaired.
>
> If the primary borrower – and you – fail to pay the charges, it will affect both of your credit scores.

You'd have to read through all of your sister's lease legalese to verify that you didn't just drop $3,000 out of the kindness of your heart but odds are very high that you were in fact liable for the cost.

When our lease ended we lucked out with a wear-and-tear clause which stated that we're not responsible for up to $1,000 of excess wear-and-tear. The line item showed we used up $700 because the car needed new tires when we returned it. Three months before the lease ended I had to shell out a few hundred for new pads and rotors so I'll call it a wash.

You did the right thing by paying the $3,000 so that your credit doesn't get ruined but now you have the tricky task of how to proceed with getting the money back from your sister.

The presumable fact that your sister has paid all of the car payments during the lease is nothing short of amazing, to be honest. Many co-signers get hit a lot worse than $3,000; I'm not saying that this statistic validates what happened but it could have been much worse.

Comment: Upvoting for your last paragraph. I agree that is pretty amazing. I wonder if some of that $3K actually included the return fee and some unpaid balance; that would actually be more believable than $3K in damages.

Comment: @TTT $3K+ in damages at dealer prices ain't that much these days. Could be just a few small-ish things with a lot of labor and at top prices for OEM parts. A decent independent mechanic using aftermarket or rebuilt parts might charge $1K for almost the same thing.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Could be, though I'm starting to think that the $3K was probably the total of everything. (Return fee + mileage overage + damage, etc.) It wouldn't surprise me if they would have been better off flipping it at CarMax...